# Apple rejected app because it's transmitting MAC Address without user permission

Tags: ios, mac-address, rubymotion

We had a recently developed app rejected by Apple. Here is their explanation:

> We found your app does not obtain user consent before collecting the
>   user's personal data, as required by theApp Store Review Guidelines.
>
> Specifically, your applications sends the device's MAC address without
>   the user's permission. Your app also sends device Contact information
>   without the user's permission.
>
> To collect personal data with your app, you must make it clear to the
>   user that their personal data will be uploaded to your server and you
>   must obtain the user's consent before the data is uploaded.
>
> iOS 6 includes new keys for specifying the reason the app will access
>   the user's protected data. When the access prompt is displayed, the
>   purpose specified in these keys is displayed in that dialog box. If
>   your application will be transmitting protected user data, the usage
>   string in your access request should clearly inform the user that
>   their data will be uploaded to your server if they consent.
>
> For more information on these keys, please see the Information
>   Property List Key Reference.

We are using the RubyMotion toolchain, and not accessing the MAC address anywhere in our app. We think it may be one of the SDK's or gems we are using.

Gemfile:

```
source :rubygems

gem 'bubble-wrap', :git => 'https://github.com/rubymotion/BubbleWrap.git'
gem 'teacup' 
gem 'rake'
gem "cocoapods", "0.13.0"
gem 'motion-cocoapods', "1.1.0"
gem 'motion-testflight'
gem 'motion-table'
gem "Parsistence"
gem 'formotion'
gem "ProMotion"
gem "motion-addressbook"
```

The only external api calls are to [Parse.com](http://www.parse.com) and to testflight, as we are using both of these SDK's.

Parse said that they do not collect the MAC address, and Testflight doesn't unless you specifically do so.

We are also using these Cocoa pods:

> 'NSData+MD5Digest'
>
> 'MBProgressHUD'
>
> 'ASIHTTPRequest'
>
> 'PHFRefreshControl'
>
> 'JSONKit'

**Question:** Do any of these gems or Cocoapods call for the MAC address?

Comment: hi Silasj, one of my game is rejected for same reason, you got solution?

Comment: @Guru We had to remove testflight from the production build, and and Apple accepted it after that.

Comment: here we are not using testFlight, any idea about these sdk facebook sdk/RevMobAds/Nextpeer/Chartboost/TouchJSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd imagine test flight or Parse could have the ability to retrieve the MAC address and even if they don't send it Apple is probably just seeing that they are accessing and sending something. I assume this because it would be really bad if any of these libraries are sending an unencrypted version of the MAC address over network so maybe Apple can just see the accessing of it. Are you by any chance using an advertising network in your app?

Comment: No, there isn't any advertising in the app.

Comment: Some of those other libraries you listed are just code and not a precompiled library. I'd search for includes like: #include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/sysctl.h>
#include <net/if.h>
#include <net/if_dl.h> to see if any are accessing the MAC address

Comment: I also wouldn't count out parse or test flight. After the UDID was deprecated the MAC address was the only guaranteed unique device identifier and I could imagine they are using that for some device verification on their end.

Comment: I just searched through the project for those and found that the Reachability pod (which we aren't using) was importing 'sys/socket.h'. We just cleaned out the pods/ directory so maybe it'll be fixed. Is there a way to track(and read) network requests using instruments?

Comment: We emailed parse directly with the feedback shown above, and they stated that they weren't using it.

Comment: Maybe you can use a program like http://www.charlesproxy.com to monitor what's being sent.

Answer (score 4):

Upgrade TestFlight to the latest SDK to fix this. From their Release Notes:

1.2.5 - May 1, 2013

Removed any access to mac address

Added AdSupport.framework requirement

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sniff traffic from your device to see what's being sent, try using [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/).