# IS MAC Id retrieval on IOS devices valid or not?

Tags: ios

Could someone please tell if the retrieval of MAC Id on iOS devices permitted by Apple or does the it reject my application  while submission to App store??

Comment: If they figure out you are using it, they will reject it.

Comment: Thanks borrrden for your response but does the Apple documentation mention anywhere that the MAC Id retrieval is invalid.

Comment: Actually, as of iOS 6, it seems that you can do it if you have the user's permission.  See here -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13317801/apple-rejected-app-because-its-transmitting-mac-address-without-user-permission

Comment: Thats exactly what I need  borrrden.Thanks a lot